# Axios not handling response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to post a new document to a database using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to React. Thankfully I can do it, but I also want log a message to the console that says "New post has been inserted".

Here is my front end code:

```
newTodo(todo){
axios.post('/todo', {
    title: todo.title,
    description: todo.description
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log('New post has been inserted!');
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

My Back End (Nodejs)

```
server.post('/todo', (req, res) => {
    // Inserting new todo
    var newTodo = new todo({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        key: '',
        date: moment().format('lll')
    });

    newTodo.save((e, savedTodo) => {
        if(e){
            console.log(e);
        } else {
            todo.findById(savedTodo._id, (e, foundTodo) => {
                if(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                } else {
                    foundTodo.key = foundTodo._id.toString();
                    foundTodo.save((e, updatedTodo) => {
                        if(e){
                            console.log(e);
                        } else {
                            console.log(updatedTodo);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

The request is successful but the message is never logged. Additionally, there are no errors logged. Please tell me what I am doing wrong or if there is another way to do this.

Comment: Check the console for errors and try setting a break point in your code if possible.

Comment: Open network tab in developer tools and check the api response what is returned  ?

Comment: are you using any middle ware?

Comment: After, 1 or 2 minutes there are two errors

POST http://localhost:3000/todo net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error

Comment: if you are using a nodejs server for /todo check the server, and check if POST is 200 OK and not pending in the NETWORK tab.

Comment: Yes I am using node.js and in network tab the POST is pending

Comment: What should I need to do?

Comment: can you show the node code?

Comment: Yes I can show the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, whenever you need to return a result, for example if you need to return: updatedTodo you need to use:

```
res.send(updatedTodo)
```